# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is duplicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation, duplicates

willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is duplicated!

```
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        ...
    }
```

It did not move at the same timing with the following.

```
    - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;
    {
        ...
    }
```

Is there any "something" alternative to doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

you may go for notification approach:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

Comment: Do you use it !!!
I have been using Objective-C for a week now.
Would you please tell us a little more if you'd like? Use `...` so that you can use it as it is.